# centre body of website

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad, web

I have created a website i have not add stylesheets or coding to make it viewable on ipad or iphone, but when you do view it on ipad, the body the document if offcentre, why is this when it's not off centre on a laptop or pc browser.

I look at some orientation coding to see if that would help but it did nada, can anyone help, i can look online but it been fruitless.

Here's the link to the website: www.mopowered.co.uk, view the source code to see if i am making a mistake, please let me know if i am doing something wrong.

All help is appreciated

Comment: > Visit this website - it should help you a lot. Especially in the future: [Should I use tables for layout?](http://shouldiusetablesforlayout.com/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="3" border="0" align="center" width="1024">
```

the align attribute is deprecated, it may be that in the newer browsers?

also I notice you're using `text-align: center` in the body element which used to center tables maybe still does, anyway it could be the smaller resolution browsers don't like this or a combination of the two, I don't really know..

try the below on the 2 x parent tables

```
<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="3" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 1024px; border: 0;">
```

that's inline styling which is not recommended, if it works you could add a class/ID and add the styles to a stylesheet as it should work the same for PC browsers and mobile devices

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using tables to create a complete website? Use `div` instead...
I believe using divs your website will look better also on iPhone or iPad.
You can do something like this:

```
// XHTML
<body>
    <div id="container">
        // Your website stuff will go here
    </div>
</body>

// CSS
body {
    // Add some style to the body like background
}
#container {
    margin: 0 auto; // This add no margin to top and bottom and auto center your div
    // Other stuff...
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am quite new to building website's so this is the way i know best. I shall go about and use div and see the outcome, thanks for the advice, i shall let you know how it comes out.